# How to force iphone to free space when storage is full?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, storage, bug

My phone (ios 13.5.1) was running out of storage, so I freed up a few Gbs of space by removing whatsapp album, photos (also clearing the recently deleted album) and a few app. On the next day the phone became unresponsive because the memory is full (no images were taken/ files downloaded or anything else resulting in data storage filling up). Stopped connecting to mobile network. It shows 285,9MB available. My data hasn't been backed up to icloud because of unknown error.
I'd like to keep my data, I don't want to do a hard reset.

Is there a way to force iphone to clear caches, system junk or manually remove some files?
Also is there a way to create a backup at this point?

What I've tried so far:

1. Remove unused apps (about 15 GBs): no result
2. Remove photos/clear Recently deleted folder: won't delete
3. Remove email accounts: no result
4. Remove messages: no result
5. Connect to iTunes on computer: error on connection
6. Troubleshoot connection error for iTunes: didn't work
7. Deleting documents manually: error "The file couldn't be saved"
8. Turning on airplane mode (no idea how it could help, but I tried): no result
9. Turning off icloud backup: didn't work
10. Clearing Safari cache: no result
11. Unloading apps: no result
12. Updating os: didn't work
13. Searching in apple support forum
14. Searching in Ask Different
15. Searching in Google

There might be something else that I've tried.

Note:
I don't want to do hard reset, because there's no backup in icloud.
I don't want to restart, because most likely it won't start and
I'm going to have to do hard reset anyway. This is from my previous
experience and the people I know.

**Edit:**

Storage

[image]

I don't remember if this is the same message when I fist saw the phone doesn't respond. But this is what I can reproduce now.

[image: error message]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the out-of-Memory error message you get, and from your storage screen?

Comment: @nohillside Hey, thanks for replying. I can't really take any screenshots from the phone :)  I'm sure the photos will do. Thanks, I updated my post.

Comment: The issue is your photos   It is domiciled larger than anything else so only fixing that will make a difference. First thing to do is connect to iCloud to get a backup. That might need another question to sort out.

Comment: Are all photos synced with iCloud Photo Library? Can you empty the trash on iCloud.com, or even disable the iCloud Library on your phone? But as mentioned above, fixing the backup issue with another question is probably the more sensible approach.

Comment: @mmmmmm Hey, I can't delete any photos from my phone now. Nothing happens when I try to. I've got lots of space in icloud, but only few photos from a few days back were backup in there. Tried deleting things from the drive and icloud, don't see any change. Can't disable icloud backups in my phone, it won't switch. Thanks.

Comment: @nohillside No, no they are not. To be precise, I can only see a few of my photos from a few days back. I tried deleting things from icloud, I don't think it makes any difference. What I'm after is my photo/video files.